# Django query : Request with startswith in an array

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

here is my code :

```
q =  [
    "78",
    "95",
    "77",
    "91",
    "92",
    "93",
    "94",
    "75",
    "27",
    "28",
    "45",
    "89",
    "10",
    "51",
    "02",
    "60",
    "27",
]
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(code_postal__startswith=item) for item in q))
result = Record14.objects.filter(query)
for r in result :
print(r)
```

I want a query with all the objects from Record14 where the code_postal begin with the values in the q array.

I have the data in my database i'am sure, but the query is empty ...

I don't understand why.

Comment: You use `and_` as a reducer, so that means that you say: that the postal code should start with 78 and should start with 10. No text can start with both at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that you use `and_` as reduce operator, so that means that you specify as condition that the `code_postal` should start with `78` and `95` at the same time. No text/number can start with `78` and `95` (and all other values) at the same time.

You can easily fix this by reducing this with `or_`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

query = reduce(or_, (Q(code_postal__startswith=item) for item in q))
result = Record14.objects.filter(query)
```

That being said, it is probably better to use a [*regular expression* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) here, like:

```
from re import escape as reescape

result = Record14.objects.filter(
    code_postal__regex= '^({})'.format('|'.join(map(reescape, q)))
)
```

For your given list `q`, this will result in a regex:

```
^(78|95|77|91|92|93|94|75|27|28|45|89|10|51|02|60|27)
```

The `^` is the start anchor here, and the pipe acts as a "union", so this regex looks for columns that start with `78`, `95`, `77`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can also (since Django 2.1) combine an annotation with a database function called [Left](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#left) and use the `__in` lookup:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Left

records = Record14.objects.annotate(
    code_postal_ini=Left('code_postal', 2)   # Take the 2 first characters of code_postal
).filter(
    code_postal_ini__in=q  # Filter if those 2 first chars are contained in q
)
```

simple.